# I don't know how to correctly remove multiples of k and m from the list)

Tags: python

I need to write a program that generates a list of N elements ranging from 1 to 10 then display the list on the screen. Remove from the list all elements that are multiples of k or m (enter k and m from the keyboard). For example, remove all numbers that are multiples of 3 or 5.

```
import random
n = int (input ('Enter the number of list items') )
c = [random.randint (1, 10) for i in range (n) ]
print (c)
k = int (input ('Enter the number from which we will determine the multiplicity.') )
m = int (input ('Enter the number from which we will determine the multiplicity.') )
for i in n:
    if c % k == 0 and c % m == 0
        c.remove (i)
print(c)
```

Comment: Your code is improperly indented, please fix it.

Comment: Side note: `random.randint (1, 10)` gives you elements ranging from 1 to 9.

Comment: If it says multiple of k **OR** m then you shouldn't use `and`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
for i in n:
    if c % k == 0 and c % m == 0
        c.remove (i)
```

To this:

```
c = [x for x in c if x % k != 0 and x % m != 0]
```